# Add space between every letter

Tags: bash, openoffice.org

How can I add spaces between every character or symbol within a UTF-8 document? E.g. `123hello!` becomes `1 2 3 h e l l o !`.

- I have `BASH`, `OpenOffice.org`, and `gedit`, if any of those can do that.
- I don't care if it sometimes leaves extra spaces in places (e.g. 2 or 3 spaces in a single place is no problem).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`sed(1)` can do this:

```
$ sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1 /g' < /etc/passwd
r o o t : x : 0 : 0 : r o o t : / r o o t : / b i n / b a s h 
d a e m o n : x : 1 : 1 : d a e m o n : / u s r / s b i n : / b i n / s h
```

It works well on e.g. UTF-8 encoded Japanese content:

```
$ file japanese 
japanese: UTF-8 Unicode text
$ sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1 /g' < japanese 
E X I F 中 の 画 像 回 転 情 報 対 応 に よ り 、 一 部 画 像 （ 特 に 『 
$
```

Comment: Isn't this simpler `sed 's/./& /g' infile`?

Comment: @JaypalSingh lol, jinx. I think I submitted [my `sed` version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8696813/207248) 10 seconds before your comment

Comment: @Jaypal: ah, yes, it is; my fault for not knowing which specific tools support `&` and which ones require the more general `\n` matching syntax.

Comment: Is there anyway to not have a trailing space?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, the easiest way I know is to use another `sed`: `sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1 /g' < /etc/passwd | sed -e 's/ $//'` -- probably this could be done another way in a single pass, but this works okay.

Comment: Or both in the same sed: `sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1 /g;s/ $//' < /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 46):

Shortest `sed` version

```
sed 's/./& /g'
```

#### Output

```
$ echo '123hello!' |  sed 's/./& /g'
1 2 3 h e l l o !
```

Obligatory `awk` version

```
awk '$1=$1' FS= OFS=" "
```

#### Output

```
$ echo '123hello!' |  awk '$1=$1' FS= OFS=" "
1 2 3 h e l l o !
```

Comment: LOL .. I thought may be this might not work on UTF8 or other encoding but it appears to work just fine. +1 :)

Comment: Is there a way to also make the string uppercase in the same awk command?

Comment: @EricWolf I would suggest you use `sed 's/./\U& /g'` for that

Comment: @SiegeX I actually figured it out since asking, `echo $MESSAGE | awk '$1=$1 {print toupper($0)}' FS= OFS=" ");`

Answer (score 8):

sed is ok but this is pure bash

```
string=hello
for ((i=0; i<${#string}; i++)); do
    string_new+="${string:$i:1} "
done
```

Comment: This generates a trailing space.

Answer (score 7):

Since you have bash, I am will assume that you have access to sed.  The following command line will do what you wish.

```
$ sed -e 's:\(.\):\1 :g' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
echo '1 23h ello  !   ' |  sed 's/\s*/ /g;s/^\s*\(.*\S\)\s*$/\1/;l'
1 2 3 h e l l o !$
1 2 3 h e l l o !
```

In retrospect a far better solution:

```
sed 's/\B/ /g' file
```

Replaces the space between letters with a space.

Comment: +1 especially for the completely different interpretation of the problem than the rest of us. :)

Answer (score 3):

I like these solutions because they do not have a trailing space like the rest
here.

GNU awk:

```
echo 123hello! | awk NF=NF FS=
```

GNU awk:

```
echo 123hello! | awk NF=NF FPAT=.
```

POSIX awk:

```
echo 123hello! | awk '{while(a=substr($0,++b,1))printf b-1?FS a:a}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
string='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
echo ${string} | sed -r 's/(.{1})/\1 /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure POSIX Shell version:

```bash
addspace() {
  __addspace_str="$1"
  while [ -n "${__addspace_str#?}" ]; do
    printf '%c ' "$__addspace_str"
    __addspace_str="${__addspace_str#?}"
  done
  printf '%c' "$__addspace_str"
}
```

Or if you need to put it in a variable:

```bash
addspace_var() {
  addspace_result=""
  __addspace_str="$1"
  while [ -n "${__addspace_str#?}" ]; do
    addspace_result="$addspace_result${__addspace_str%${__addspace_str#?}} "
    __addspace_str="${__addspace_str#?}"
  done
  addspace_result="$addspace_result$__addspace_str"
}

addspace_var abc
echo "$addspace_result"
```

Tested with dash, ksh, zsh, bash (+ bash --posix), and busybox ash.

## Explanation

```bash
${x#?}
```

This parameter expansion removes the first character of x. `${x#...}` in general removes a prefix given by a pattern, and `?` matches any single character.

```bash
printf '%c ' "$str"
```

The `%c` format parameter transforms the string argument into its first character, so the full format string `'%c '` prints the first character of the string followed by a space. Note that if the string was empty this would cause issues, but we already checked that it wasn't before, so it's fine. To print the first character safely in any situation we can use `'%.1s'`, but I like living dangerously :3j

```bash
${x%${x#?}}
```

This is an alternate way to get the first character of the string. We already know that ${x#?} is all but the first character. Well, ${x%...} removes ... from the end of x, so ${x%${x#?}} removes all but the first character from the end of x, leaving only the first one.

```bash
__prefixed_variable_names
```

POSIX doesn't define `local`, so to avoid variable conflicts it's safer to create unique names that are unlikely to clobber each other. I am starting to experiment using M4 to generate unique names while not having to destroy my code every time but it's probably overkill for people who don't use shell as much as me.

```
[ -n "${str#?}" ]
```

Why not just `[ -n "$str" ]`? It's to avoid the dreaded trailing space, it's also why we have a little statement guy at the bottom there outside the loop. The loops goes until the string is one character long, then we finish outside of it so we can append this last character without adding a space.

## When should I use this?

This is good for small inputs in long running loops, since it avoids the overhead of calling an external process, but for larger inputs it starts lagging behind fast, specially the `var` version. (I fault the `${x%${x#?}}` trick).

#### Benchmark Commands

```
# addspace
time dash -c ". ./addspace.sh; for x in $(seq -s ' ' 1 10000); do addspace \"$input\" >/dev/null; done"
# addspace_var
time dash -c ". ./addspace.sh; for x in $(seq -s ' ' 1 10000); do addspace_var \"$input\" >/dev/null; done"
# sed for comparison
time dash -c ". ./addspace.sh; for x in $(seq -s ' ' 1 10000); do echo \"$input\" |  sed 's/./& /g' >/dev/null; done"
```

#### Input Length = 3

```bash
      addspace     addspace_var  sed  

real  0m0,106s     0m0,106s      0m10,651s
user  0m0,077s     0m0,075s      0m9,349s
sys   0m0,029s     0m0,031s      0m3,030s
```

#### Input Length = 200

```bash
      addspace     addspace_var  sed  

real  0m6,050s     0m47,115s     0m11,049s
user  0m5,557s     0m46,919s     0m9,727s
sys   0m0,488s     0m0,068s      0m3,085s
```

#### Input Length = 1000

```bash
      addspace     addspace_var  sed  

real  0m55,989s    TBD           0m11,534s           
user  0m53,560s    TBD           0m10,214s
sys   0m2,428s     TBD           0m2,975s
```

(Yeah, I was waiting a bit for that last var one.)

In situations like this you can simply check the length of the input and call the appropriate function for maximum performance.

```bash
addspace() {
  if [ ${#1} -lt 100 ]; then
    addspace_builtins "$1"
  else
    addspace_proccess "$1"
  fi
}
```