# bash - searching for a text in a file and storing it into a variable

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I am trying to search for a text in a file and store it into a variable.

My file looks something like this:

```
Type: Furniture
Color: Blue
Version: 1
```

I am trying to search for the Version number and store it into a variable and increment it. This number is unknown to me when I am searching the file. So far I have something like this.

```
VERSIONNUMBER=//Somehow I want to get the version # from the file. 
VERSIONNUMBER=`expr $VERSIONNUMBER + 1'

sed -i "s/Version:.*/Version=$VERSIONNUMBER/" filename
```

Am I on the right track so far or is there a better way of doing this? I'm having trouble searching for the version number. I keep getting syntax errors. Any help is much appreciated.

```
VERSIONNUMBER=`sed -i "s/Version:/*" filename`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a job for awk

```
 awk '/Version:/{$2++}1' ./infile > ./outfile
```

#### Example

```
$ awk '/Version:/{$2++}1' ./infile
Type: Furniture
Color: Blue
Version: 2
```

#### Explanation

`/Version:/` Match only lines that contain the text 'Version:'

`$2++`: Get the 2nd field, of which awk delimits with a space by default, and increment it

`{...}1`: A shortcut to tell awk to `print` out the lines after it does any alterations

Comment: More precisely, the `1` is a new pattern, one which is always true, with the default action, which is `print $0`.  (An Awk script is a sequence of `pattern / action` pairs.)  Thus `awk 1 /etc/passwd` is a slower variant of `cat /etc/passwd`.

Comment: Thanks, very clear explanations! This was exactly what I was looking to do except it's much much more simpler. It doesn't seem like I'm able to store the updated version back into the same file so I'm planning to pipe `./infile > ./outfile` like you suggested and then replace the old `./infile` with the new `./outfile`. Thanks again!

Comment: @user459811 yes, `awk` doesn't support inplace edit like `sed -i`. But note that `sed -i` is not portable, it's a GNUism.  And as im sure you probably already found out, if you attempt to redirect a file onto itself you end up with hosing the file.  You'll need to manually copy it over.

Comment: I'd not seen the idiom before, so I needed to work out how it worked, to see if it is portable to all versions of awk or not.  I believe it is fully portable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, it should be portable. The other idiom I see quite a bit is `{$1=$1}` if all you want to do is change one of the separators.  I used that one just today [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8696813/207248). For some reason `awk` won't change the separators unless it thinks it made a change to one of the fields.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to overwrite the file in situ, then you can use Perl instead of Awk.

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's/^(Version: )(\d+)/$x=$2+1,"$1$x"/e' "$@"
```

The `.bak` saves a backup of `filename` in `filename.bak`; if you don't want the backup, drop the `.bak` from the command line (but leave the `-i` there).  The `e` modifier on the regex means treat the replacement as an expression.  The values `$2` etc are readonly, so save the incremented value to `$x` and then use that as part of the string.  The comma operator evaluates its LHS, then its RHS.