# bash/sed/awk create transcription file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a list of WAV files named word.wav. How can I create a transcription file as described in http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam, formatted this way: 

`<s> w o r d </s> (word)`

Example: If the file's name is `blue.wav`, then the line should be `<s> b l u e </s> (blue)`.

Comment: @EricRenouf I've managed to get spaces and the <s> tags (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696751/add-space-between-every-letter and http://www.shellhacks.com/en/Add-Character-to-the-Beginning-or-to-the-End-of-Each-Line-using-AWK-and-SED) respectively, but I can't seem to find a way to get the (word) part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU awk you could use the following `awk` command to strip the extension from a filename and produce the output you want:

```
 awk '{gsub( /.[^.]*$/, "", $1);spaces=$1; gsub( /./, "& ", spaces); print "<s> " spaces "</s> ("$1")"}'
```

e.g.,

```
$ a=blue.wav
$ echo $a | awk '{gsub( /.[^.]*$/, "", $1);spaces=$1; gsub( /./, "& ", spaces); print "<s> " spaces "</s> ("$1")"}'
<s> b l u e </s> (blue)
```