# Pure Bash replacement capturing groups

Tags: regex, bash, replace

I have this example string:

```
test_string="13A6"
```

This chars/digits can be from 0 to 9 and from A to F.

I want this output:

```
1 3 A 6
```

I have this working:

```
result=$(echo ${test_string} | sed 's/./& /g')
```

I want to do it without sed... and I have another solution which I don't like too much... is dirty :S

```
[[ ${test_string} =~ ^([0-9A-F])([0-9A-F])([0-9A-F])([0-9A-F]) ]] && result="${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
```

I want, if possible, to use pure bash with the syntax `result=${variable//pattern/replacement}` but not sure how to do like "&" in sed to reference the matched char itself on this kind of pure bash syntax. Any bash guru? :)

Comment: With a loop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32545111/3776858

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this (no external utility called):

```
str="13A6"
[[ $str =~ ${str//?/(.)} ]]
printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}"
```

Result (without a trailing space):

```
"1 3 A 6"
```

Or, if you need to use a different separator:

```
[[ $str =~ ${str//?/(.)} ]]
( IFS=$'\n'; printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}")
```

Or, in a function, IFS may be local to the function:

```
divide(){ 
    [[ $1 =~ ${1//?/(.)} ]]
    local IFS=${2:-' '}
    printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}"
}

divide "13A6" "-"            # will output 1-3-A-6 in this example.
```

This works like this:

```
           ${str//?/(.)}              # Replace each character with "(.)".  
[[ $str =~               ]]           # Match the regex "(.)(.)(.) … …"  
                                      # capturing each character matched  
                                      # in the array "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"  

printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}"  # Forget array index 0 and
                                      # convert the array to one string 
                                      # using the first character
                                      # of "$IFS" as separator
                                      # (no trailing separator).
```

Thanks to @chepner for the recommendation to change a `@` to a `*` in the array. That avoids the need to use a temporal array or the positional parameters.

Comment: This is very nice. You don't need to overwrite the positional parameters, though; `echo "\"${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}\""` works just as well, or you could populate an array with the capture groups: `arr=( "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}" )`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's as pure as you want :

```
test_string="13A6"
length=$( expr length "$test_string" )
s=""
for (( i=1;i<=${length};i++)) 
do
  c=$( expr substr "${test_string}" $i 1 )
  s=${s}" "$c
done
echo $s
```

Res :

```
1 3 A 6
```

Or purest (without external program) with help of chepner.

```
test_string="13A6"
s=""
for ((i=0;i<${#test_string};i++))
do
  s=${s}" "${test_string:i:1}
done
echo $s
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `expr` here; you can get the length of a string with `${#test_string}` and you can get individual characters from a string with `${test_string:i:1}`.