# How save each Capturing Groups of a bash regex?

Tags: regex, bash, sh, capturing-group

To make it really simple, I must use a regex to select string in a complex file.
I would like to "save" in a file some part of the regex selection. So I use capturing groups and... I don't know how to use th result.

For ex:
list.txt :

> abc 123 def 456

Here my regex with capture group :

```
(\d{3}) (\w{3})
```

The shell command with grep for example (can be something else, I don't care):

```
egrep '(\d{3}) (\w{3})' list.txt
```

How do I save or use every \d{3} and \w{3} results?
I can't just use

```
egrep '\d{3}' > digit.txt
```

Because the capture group is just a small part of a bigger regex

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2777579/1707353) will help?

Comment: `egrep` *isn't* a shell regex at all -- grep is an external command, not part of the shell, and the shell has no access to its state. Native shell regex syntax is more like `re='([[:digit:]]{3} ([^[:space:]]+)'; [[ $str =~ $re ]]`, which will save your capture groups in the shell variable `BASH_REMATCH`. (Note that the syntax there is baseline ERE -- `\d` and `\w` are extensions taken from PCRE; some platforms offer them, others don't, and it's unsafe to assume they'll be available since which features are available in native-shell regexes depends on the local C library).

Comment: See [Pure bash replacement capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773834/pure-bash-replacement-capturing-groups)

Comment: Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52338465/edit) and add some lines and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

`sed` will work too:

```
sed 's/.*\([0-9][0-9][0-9] [a-z][a-z][a-z]\).*/\1/' ./list.txt
```

Sorry, my old vm with ubuntu doesn't seem to support the \d or \w shortcuts.

Comment: That's not just about your "old vm" -- `\d` or `\w` aren't part of even the very latest version of the POSIX ERE standard; they aren't *supposed* to work. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html

Comment: It was just a really simple example. I use capture groups because my regex is big and complex and exporting the whole result will not help me I think. The big regex is here to select some lines in a big file. The capture group to select small part of those big lines.
I can maybe find something with grep and cut...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} and ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}