# How to store a continous number in array, bash scripting?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

It is easy to declare and store a number in array but problem is that the user gives input 1234 and i wanted to store this numbers as $array[0]=1, $array[1]=2, $array[2]=3, $array[3]=4 but instead what actually happens is that $array[0]=1234, $array[1]=null, $array[2]=null, $array[3]=null. I don't know how to store each number separately

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a key
read -p "Enter the encryption key: " numbers
key=($numbers)
echo ${key[0]} 
echo ${key[1]}
echo ${key[2]}
echo ${key[3]}.
```

Actual output:

Enter the encryption key: 1234

1234

null

null

null

Desired output:

Enter the encryption key: 1234

1

2

3

4

Thank you, in advance :)

Comment: See: [Add space between every letter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32545111/3776858)

Comment: Do you really need an empty line between the output? Please format that code.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a possibility to use

```
key=(`grep -o . <<< "$numbers"`)
```

And you can access different letters in $numbers without creating an array by using a substring notation `${string:initial_index:length_of_substring}`:

```
echo ${numbers:0:1}
echo ${numbers:1:1}
echo ${numbers:2:1}
echo ${numbers:3:1}
```

Comment: @3xploit guy: If you would like to use an array: `for ((i=0; i<${#numbers}; i++)); do key[$i]="${numbers:$i:1}"; done`

Answer (score 0):

You can try.

```
declare -a key
read -p "Enter the encryption key: " numbers
while read -n1 input; do
  key+=("$input")
done < <(printf '%s' "$numbers")

printf '%s\n' "${key[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how you're using `read` so you already assume that there are no spaces in the key, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare str
read -p "Enter the encryption key: " str

# replace each character with that character + space
spaced=$(echo "$str" | sed 's/\(.\)/\1 /g')

# without quotes, array elements will be each of the space-separated strings
numbers=( $spaced )

printf "array element %s\n" "${numbers[@]}"
```

Output:

```
Enter the encryption key: hello123
array element h
array element e
array element l
array element l
array element o
array element 1
array element 2
array element 3
```